# Determine if $(x^5+x^3y^2+x^2y^3+y^5-y)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Q[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

I am guessing $\mathfrak p=(x^5+x^3y^2+x^2y^3+y^5-y)$ is a prime ideal. Here is my attempt:

Every $y^n$ term for $n\geq 5$ can be reduce to a lower degree modulo $\mathfrak p$ by using $$y^5 = y-x^2y^3-x^3y^2-x^5$$ so that under modulo $\mathfrak p$ every polynomial is of the form $$y^4p_4(x)+y^3p_3(x)+y^2p_2(x)+yp_1(x)+p_0(x)$$ but this is all I have got.

I am guessing $$\Bbb Q[x,y]/\mathfrak p\simeq \Bbb Q[x]\oplus \Bbb Q[x]\oplus \Bbb Q[x]\oplus \Bbb Q[x]\oplus \Bbb Q[x]$$

Comment: The question is equivalent to whether the given polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ or not. Hint: try Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Mark Following your comment, looking at it as a polynomial in $x$, the highest degree coefficient $1$ is not in the prime ideal $\Bbb Q[x,y](y)$ while other coefficients $y^2,y^3,y^5-y$ are all in $\Bbb Q[x,y](y)$. Finally the "constant" $y^5-y$ is not in $\Bbb Q[x,y](y^2)$ as desired. Is this right?

Comment: Pretty much. To be precise, you work in $\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$ here, so the coefficients belong to the domain $\mathbb{Q}[y]$, and $(y)$ is a prime ideal in this domain. (we don't think of it as an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ here) If that's what you meant, this is correct.

Comment: @Mark Yes exactly. Thank you.